# Do I need to restart the server everytime I edit my JS code? - Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I started playing with Meteor. Unfortunately a few things are slowing me down.

I am editing the JS code (I'm using CoffeeScript) but the new code doesn't seem to get picked up and need to restart the server.

Restarting the server takes a while too. So after each edit need to wait 10 seconds in order to see the outcome... a bit tedious.

Anything I can do in order to speed the editing and testing loop?

Thanks guys. Help would be awesome :)

### Edit

Ok found out that you can run meteor in test mode using

```
meteor run --production=false
```

But when modifying the coffeescript file it still takes 10 seconds or more to reload the page again. If someone has any ideas it would be helpful. I guess I'll try without CoffeeScript for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to automatically restart the server once you make code changes.

Comment: stewe: Thanks a lot! I tried `supervisor -w ./ -x meteor run` but the process keeps restarting. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a cool tool, and applicable, but the correct answer is definitely to run in dev mode (production=false).

Comment: @benson production=false is definitely too sluggish even with js files. Restarting process on file change would definitely work better for now... I don't know why meteor takes so long to reload, would be good to know if it is an issue with everyone.

Comment: I can tell you that it reloads extremely fast for me -- probably under 50 ms.  If raw JS code is still that slow for you, there's something else at play here.

Comment: @benson interesting thanks for that...  I have a clean ubuntu 10.04 install and installed the stable packages of node and npm using the preferred methods, so I'm not sure how to proceed with this.  :(

Comment: @RadiantHex That's interesting. I have a clean 11.10 install that works fine.  I did do my install via a git clone, but other than that it's pretty typical.  Maybe try doing the install with the build-from-scratch approach?  I suppose it's possible there's some weird interaction with the binaries on your system.